# Is there a good, full-featured EPUB to PDF converter?

Tags: software-recommendation, pdf, epub

There are tons of PDF to EPUB converters but almost no EPUB TO PDF.

Only thing I've found is a [free online converter](http://www.convertfiles.com/convert/ebook/EPUB-to-PDF.html) (takes some time to upload, lacks the cover and the sidebar navigation) and a [shareware](http://www.ebook-converter.com/epub-pdf-converter.htm) (that I couldn't get to work).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does [Calibre](http://www.calibre-ebook.com/) work? It offers [Ebook Format Conversion](http://manual.calibre-ebook.com/faq.html) for a lot of formats, quote from the FAQ:

> Calibre supports the conversion of many input formats to many output formats. It can convert every input format in the following list, to every output format.
>
> Input Formats: CBZ, CBR, CBC, CHM, DJVU, EPUB, FB2, HTML, HTMLZ, LIT, LRF, MOBI, ODT, PDF, PRC, PDB, PML, RB, RTF, SNB, TCR, TXT, TXTZ
>
> Output Formats: EPUB, FB2, OEB, LIT, LRF, MOBI, HTMLZ, PDB, PML, RB, PDF, RTF, SNB, TCR, TXT, TXTZ

Comment: Not as far as I've tested, seems to be only a reader and library.

Comment: Calibre definitely does conversions, that is the main thing I use it for and I just tested epub to pdf

Comment: Oh ok, I had another try and indeed it does. The labelling of the menu options is a bit strange. @Mark do you have any tip on getting the sidebar bookmarks ?

Comment: No I usually convert to epub as I want the display to choose how to show the text not the author so I want word wrapping etc - anything but pdf

Answer (score 2):

You can try [Go4ePub.com](http://www.go4epub.com).

According to my experience the results are slightly better than with Calibre.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to try this free online converter [convertio.co](https://convertio.co/epub-pdf/) , I have used it for a very long time without any problems ever!